# how can I make variadic template function with a function pointer as non type argument?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

what I want to achieve is create a temple similar to following:

```
template<type R, type T, type S, auto F, class ...Fargs>
R create(T input, Fargs... fargs)
{
  S a = F(input, fargs ...);
  return some_func(a, input.b);
}
```

Then I would like to call it like

```
int x = create<int, SomeClass, float, SomeFunc_to_apply>(2, someObj, 8.0f, 3, "whatever", "it", "needs");
```

Comment: Your posted code (as interpreted from your speudocode) just works for me: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/dZ3FFJ Did you run into a specific problem while implementing this?

Comment: I think yours is working because you do not have default args.

Comment: That why you should provide mcve.(Minimal Complete Verifiable example).

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify a little:

```
template <auto F, typename T, class ...Fargs>
decltype(auto) create(T input, Fargs... fargs)
{
  auto a = F(input, fargs ...);
  return some_func(a, input.b);
}
```

And use it:

```
SomeClass someObj;
float SomeFunc_to_apply(SomeClass, float, int, const char*, const char*, const char*);
int x = create<SomeFunc_to_apply>(someObj, 8.0f, 3, "whatever", "it", "needs");
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c0f63b923bebc556)

Comment: thanks for the auto tricks on return. But it seems if F has default args. For example: `func(SomeClass, float x=1.0f, int b=2, ...)`. Then call the template as `create<func>(someObj)` It will not work. Any idea?

Comment: @Wang: signature of `void func(SomeClass, float x=1.0f, int b=2)` is `void(SomeClass, float, int)`, so you lose default value. You might write it in a lamdba from C++2a [Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fe752112f6e39089)